# Get Time zone offset

Tags: jquery, json

I want to get time zone offset of given city. I am using weather online api. 
http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/tz.ashx?q=Lahore&format=json&callback=crm&key=j7cf7epyawudqvbkf3cvc7r2

and it return

```
crm({
    "data": {
        "request": [{
            "query": "Lahore, Pakistan",
            "type": "City"
        }],
        "time_zone": [{
            "localtime": "2013-11-27 10:46",
            **"utcOffset": "5.0"**
        }]
    }
})
```

now how I get utcoffset value using jSon and jQuery
 if anyone have an idea please share with me
thanks in advance

Comment: var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); ??

Comment: @AamirAfridi this is based on the client (timezone, time, ...)setup, not necessarily a city - which is what the OP wants ...

Comment: Of course, he can convert localtime to date object first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `crm()` function to your page (for the callback):

```
<script>
function crm(timeData) {
    // alert first offset
    alert(timeData['data']['time_zone'][0]['utcOffset']);
}
</script>
```

Comment: you could explain the magic :) queryString-paramter "callback" is used as the jsonp-callback (...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/tz.ashx?q=Lahore&format=json&key=j7cf7epyawudqvbkf3cvc7r2",
            success: function(res){
                alert(res.data.time_zone[0].utcOffset);
            },
            dataType: "jsonp"
        });
    });
  </script>
```

Hope it will help

Comment: hi sonusindhu,
thanks for reply but it is working in IE but not in Crome Browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can better use xml to get the data easily in xml format

http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/tz.ashx?q=Lahore&format=xml&callback=crm&key=j7cf7epyawudqvbkf3cvc7r2

```
-<data>
  -<request
     <type>City</type>
     <query>Lahore, Pakistan</query>
  </request>
  -<time_zone>
     <localtime>2013-11-27 17:42</localtime>
     <utcOffset>5.0</utcOffset>
  </time_zone>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0):

How I callBack this function
in below code where is error.

```
function time() {           
        var url = "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/tz.ashx?q=Lahore&format=json&callback=crm&key=j7cf7epyawudqvbkf3cvc7r2";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: data,
            success: crm,
           // dataType: dataType
            dataType: "jsonp",            

            jsonCallback: 'crm'       
        });
    }

    function crm(timeData) {
        // alert first offset
        alert(timeData['data']['time_zone'][0]['utcOffset']);
    }
```