# How do you account for time-zone offset when retriving an "All Day" event from Google Calendar API?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, google-calendar-api

I have an Ajax call to retrieve information from a public Google Calendar:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/{CalID}/public/full?start-min={StartTime}&start-max={endTime}&alt=json-in-script&callback=?";
      dataType: 'json',
      timeout: 3000,
      success: function( data ) { ProcessData(data);},
});
```

Within function `ProcessData(data)` I have the following statement:

```
StartTime = new Date(data.feed.entry[i].gd$when[j].startTime);
```

which stores in `StartTime` a `Date()` object with the date a particular event starts. Google normally uses ISO 8601 time format: YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20+01:00) and this works just fine. However, for "All Day" events the format is only in the form: YYYY-MM-DD (eg 1997-07-16) (Which is allowed by W3 http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) and in this case `new Date()` will interpret this as GMT. This is, will correct that particular date to your local time zone even if the event was already created in your local time-zone. In my particular case, when retrieving an "All Day" event on, say, April 7th 2014 happening in my time zone would return a string as if it was 5 hours earlier

```
  new Date("2014-04-07")
```

returns Sun Apr 06 2014 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT) which is off by 5 hours. (See the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22882805/why-is-date2014-04-07-parsed-to-sat-apr-05-2014-172615-gmt-0500-cest?noredirect=1#comment34940474_22882805) for more details on date parsing)

Have you ever had to deal with this issue when using Google Calendar? And if so, how did you solve it? Should I be using a different method instead of new Date() that would actually account for the time zone?

Google's JSON response contains a parameter feed.timezone, which contains the Olson's Time Zone ID but I'd need a way to convert (hopefully another Ajax call or something like that) that ID into an actual offset. I found the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242645/get-time-zone-offset) in this forum but the problem with this is that the parameter this API needs is the actual city and not the time Zone ID making me then to somehow make the translation from time zone ID to a city to pass to the URL string.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you say ISO 8601 strings with an offset "work just fine", are you leaving parsing up to the Date constructor, or are you doing it yourself? Some browsers won't correctly parse an ISO string, and more won't correctly parse a string with an offset. There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22827052/creating-new-date-object-which-includes-timezone-identifier) that shows how to parse an ISO string with offset for all browsers.

In regard to how to deal with dates, that is an issue that only has a business logic answer. If it is interpreted as an ISO 8601 string, then in any timezone that is west of Greenwich (or more than an hour west during its daylight saving time), it will result in a date one day before. If you wish to treat it as a local date, you'll need to first test the string to see if it's just a date and if so, treat it as local, e.g.

```
if (/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/.test(dateString) {
  // treat as date
} else {
  // treat as date and time
}
```

Parsing the string as a local date is pretty simple:

```
// Expect a date string in ISO 8601 format YYYY-MM-DD
// Date is created as a local date
function parseLocalDateTime(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D+/g);
  return new Date(s[0], --s[1], s[2]);
}
```